# Is it possible to run a servlet on jetty without a web.xml file?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am tying to run a servlet using Jetty but only by using java code(embedded jetty).
Here are my two classes :

ExampleServer.java :

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 7/8/14.
 */
public class ExampleServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8080);

        server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/hello");
        context.addServlet(HelloServlet.class, "/");

        HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{context, new DefaultHandler()});
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

HelloServlet.java :

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 7/8/14.
 */
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello from HelloServlet</h1>");
        response.getWriter().println("session=" + request.getSession(true).getId());
    }
}
```

Now when I am trying to access  `http://localhost:8080/hello` I get the following error :

HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /hello/. Reason:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No SessionManager
```

Any ideas on how to fix that?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if you embed the server and supply the correct parameters at startup. That is, you invoke your own main

Comment: So I must add something at my main method?

Comment: You see the web.xml data is just configuration data. You supply the parameters when you start up the server. Google embedded jetty and you will see how to pass the parameters

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed a step,

```
context.addServlet(HelloServlet.class, "/");
context.setSessionHandler(new org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler());
```

Normally, the configuration file is used to set that by default (or to use [JDBCSessionManager](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/JDBCSessionManager.html) for a cluster). Also, you only need this because you called `request.getSession(true).getId()`